# My daughters chain keeps falling off

Tags: chain, derailleur, drivetrain-slipping

The derailleur is not feeding the chain to the cassette properly it comes off the cog about half way round and gets spat off the cogs completely.

It looks like the derailleur is bent outwards which unusual can I just bend this back into alignment?

Comment: Can you add some photos to the question?

Comment: From the smallest cog or from the largest cog?

Comment: Photos!  Could be the derailleur itself, or the mount it secures to.  That could be integral to the frame or a separate part.   Steel can generally be straightened, aluminium will likely snap or at least weaken when straightened.

Answer (score 2):

Raise the rear wheel up somehow so that you can spin the pedals at least half revolution and check where the derailleur is guiding the chain when you spin up the wheel with the pedal, gently accelerating from still stand. Try to regulate the tension of the cable that controls the position of the derailleur. There is usually one regulator at the gear lever (around the cable) and it may also be another. There is also additional screw that sets the position of the fastest gear (smallest cog), to prevent it falling down. Be careful with the spinning wheel.

If the derailleur is so bent that cannot be regulated this way, do not even know. I would yield to visit a bicycle shop at this point instead.